# Python - Selenium scrape table from the website

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I want to scrape the table "Ownership Reports" from https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/own-disp?action=getissuer&CIK=0000320193

How would I scrape this table information? I'm using Selenium.

I tried the following code `my_output = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table')[0].text.split('\n')[1:]`using XPath but the output looks horrible.

I expect to put this data in a Pandas DataFrame. Can anyone share some thoughts? Thank you so much.

---

```
for tr in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table'):
tds = tr.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')
output_lst = [td.text for td in tds]
```

I found a solution above - although it's not that elegant but can do the work. I look forward to seeing a better solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
output_lst = []

for tr in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table'):
tds = tr.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')
output_lst = [td.text for td in tds]
```

The coding above works